# Power BI: Published report can´t connect to the gateway

Tags: connection, powerbi

I have a problem that I can not figure out. When I publish a report trough the Power BI Desktop, I get an error:

> Publishing succeeded, but the published report can´t connect to the
>   data source because we were unable to find a gateway. Please install
>   and configure an enterprise gateway

I have installed and configured the  On-premises data gateway (today, so it is the latest version). local network status is connected. I have Azure Service Bus **on**

I also have configured datasource in the power bi and it shows connection successful. When I try to view the report on app.powerbi, I get the following error:

> This data source can´t be accessed by a data gateway: Server:
>   localhost; Database: daa
>   I don't know why it shows the server as local host. When I open the report from reporting services It shows the server connection as IP xx.xxx.xxx.xx WHY does it say now localhost?

On the reportservice it works fine, but not when uploaded to app.powerbi

I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

This issue with publishing could be mismatching credentials. If you are receiving a success message for data connection, can publish but it can't connect to the datasource, make sure both data source servers match EXACTLY in PowerBI desktop and online in manage gateways. For example if you have 192.168.1.25\db as your desktop data source server connection then it must be the same in the online Power BI Gateway datasource as otherwise your report publishing will fail. If they dont match (perhaps you have used a servername instead of IP) then your Gateway will be connected but the publishing wont work. Hope this helps someone :)